# Paypal SDK dont register in database

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to make a Paypal payment aplication, i am in fact following a tutorial about how to use Paypal-SDK just to learn how to use it, and even when the payment happends successfully (in that part it works just fine), for some reason, **i just can make the app to insert data in the database to register the transaction actualy happend**.

I already try some stuffs to fix it:

1) I already check the database name, password & permitions.

2) I already try to ask for help with the people who make the tutorial (in fact, i try twice)

3) I already try to ask for help in the Paypal-SDK github

4) I already try to ask to another people/places/site

5) Yes, i already check all the logs, the Paypal log, the apache log & the mysql log, and it doesn't return me any error messages.

So, here i am, in StackOverflow asking for help to fix it..

The tutorial link is in youtube and is this:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWE_c8jjW5OeweL1c_8uqcnW

this is the code i have:

start.php

```
<?php

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;

session_start();

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// API
$api = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        'Abxr4WOfNsBDlEvCmDdpNnUNdTuRx2PcAALwF1IBh978K42B2q5z8VZJaURCpJtNXO0H3XefO1q-zoSt', // Client Id
        'EM81APj_87_BVyLsltZLqW5ZOhsE9H57mTG13sbrlmGhXPu2DLtuYOGHhDMzZir1rsLY2RgUhiwsyTz_' // Secret
        )
    );

$api->setConfig(['mode' => 'sandbox',
                 'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
                 'log.LogEnabled' => true,
                 'log.FileName' => 'logPaypal.txt',
                 'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE',
                 'validation.level' => 'log'
                ]);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=paypal', 'root', 'kulturu01');

$user = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE id = :user_id
");

$user->execute(['user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);

$user = $user->fetchObject();
?>
```

payment.php

```
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;

require '../scr/start.php';

$payer = new Payer();
$details = new Details();
$amount = new Amount();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$payment = new Payment();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

// Payer
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

// Details
$details->setShipping('1.00')
    ->setTax('0.00')
    ->setSubtotal('1.00'); //feed for membership

// Amount
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal('2.00') // Shipping + Tax + Subtotal + Everything else you need to charge
    ->setDetails($details);

// Transaction
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setDescription('Membership');

$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

// Redirect URLs

$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost:1313/PayPal/PayPall/Pay.php?approved=true')
    ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost:1313/PayPal/PayPall/cancelled.php?approved=false');

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {

    $payment->create($api);

    // Print some stuffs for debugging
    /*echo "Payment Id is " . $payment->getId();
    exit;*/

    // Generate and store hash
    $hash = md5($payment->getId());
    $_SESSION['paypal_hash'] = $hash;

    // Prepare and execute transaction storage
    $store= $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO transanctions_paypal (user_id, payment_id, hash, complete)
        VALUES (:user_id, :payment_id, :hash, 0)
    ");


    $store->execute([
        'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
        'payment_id' => $payment->getId(),
        'hash' => $hash
    ]); 

    /*$store->execute([
        'user_id' => '123123123',
        'payment_id' => '111111111',
        'hash' => '321321'
    ]);*/

    echo "Payment Created Completed Successfully";

} catch (PayPalConnectionException $e) {
    echo $e->getData();
    // Perhaps log an error
    echo "Payment Just Fail";

    header('Location: ../PayPall/error.php');


}  catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit(1);

}



foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {

    if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
        $redirectUrl = $link->getHref();
    }
}



header('Location: '. $redirectUrl);

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'scr/start.php';

var_dump($user);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <?php if ($user->member): ?>
            <p>Eres un miembro!</p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p>No Eres un miembro!. <a href="member/payment.php">Vuelte un miembro!</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any question, comment or any other kind of sugestion than help to improve the question, or obtain and answer, or something directly related too would be much apreciated as much as a good answer.

If you consider than i need to gave more info, just ask about what info you need and i'll add it to the post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did harcoding the value on insert worked ? `$store->execute([
        'user_id' => '123123123',
        'payment_id' => '111111111',
        'hash' => '321321'
    ]);`

Comment: When we try to hardcode the insert doesn't work, in fact, we try to debug it using that to see if the information enter the area, but it doesn't insert that info on the database, thats why is there, in the code, commented. Any ideas?